# вывод строки в цикле после каждой 3 того итерации

Tags: php, циклы

Помогите выводит правильно строку в цикле например есть div в цикле начиная с первого и пропуская 2 итерации хочу выводит в div класс test что бы получилось как то так:

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

как правильно реализовать такую схему в `php` точно не помню как было наверное в цикле нужно добавить например так:

```
$test = 2%;
```

и через if проверят, помогите вспомнит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это реализуется так: `$i % 3`. [Арифметический оператор](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.arithmetic.php) "деление по модулю": `%` выдаёт остаток от деления.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
  $test = 'test';
  if($i % 3) $test = '';
  echo "#$i: $test\n";
}
```

[Этот код](https://repl.it/NyFT/0) выведет:

```
#0: test
#1: 
#2: 
#3: test
#4: 
#5: 
#6: test
```

Comment: Точно "деление по модулю" спасибо, даже не знал как погуглит.